# What are the suggested Java options for JNI intensive program?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I tried to optimize my JNI intensive Java program by playing around with the Java optimization options described [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html#PerformanceTuning).  However, so far I didn't find any of them could affect performance.  Can I know what are the suggested Java options or guideline for JNI intensive program? or Java options just simply have no effect on JNI intensive programs?

Comment: Crossing the JNI boundary is expensive. You should try to minimise the number of JNI calls, by aggregating the functionality on the Java side, and the functionality on your native-code side, so you don't have to travel back and forth quite so frequently.

Comment: I tried to minimize number of JNI calls by caching frequently-used method-id field-ids, but the whole Java code is still JNI intensive as we already have a c++ library.

Comment: Write a wrapper facade, on the C++ side, that encapsulates as much of the C++-side operations as possible. You may also need to write a wrapper facade for the Java-side code, too. The general idea is to minimise the number of crossovers to the greatest degree possible.

Comment: But after doing that, is there anything I could tune the performance further (such as the Java options?)

Comment: I don't know of any such options (but then, I haven't looked very hard).

Comment: If it's JNI-intensive how could the Java options have any significant effect? That could only happen if it was *Java*-intensive.